# Error in respond webhook to user in telegram bot

Tags: php, codeigniter, telegram-bot, telegram-webhook

I have a telegram bot that respond to me perfectly but it doesn't respond to other users and as I see in `getWebhookinfo` it return an error `Wrong response from the webhook: 500 Internal Server Error`. I double check everything in the code
that's ok and work fine.

In addition increase `pending_update_count` in every message that other user sent to bot.

Of course I have no problem in my account :|
For more info I use Codeigniter MVC for my bot.

Comment: Did you check your error log?

Answer (score 0):

You can try POST to your own server to test and debug yourself.

Try this

```
curl -v \
-X POST \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d '{"update_id": 754000000, "message": {"message_id": 157367, "from": {"id": 109780439, "first_name": "Sean", }, "chat": {"id": 109780439, "first_name": "Sean", }, "text": "Hello World"}}' \
https://localhost/telegram/hook.php
```

I think you will see error message.